# Interpret manufacturer data through Flutter reactive BLE

Tags: dart, bluetooth-lowenergy

Rather new to Bluetooth Low-energy devices, and having recently purchased a bunch of trackers off Amazon, decided to write a little application to see what type of information I can get from these.

The trackers are from a Chinese company, and they don't have a ton of information around advertisement information, so I'm playing by best guess here.

What I've been able to achieve so far, through Flutter Reactive BLE, is to find the devices by their ID (filter out additional noise I don't care about) and pull information like RSSI, Name and ID from it.

Now I want to interpret the manufacturerData object, screenshot attached of just one of them, and can't seem to get anything concrete from it.

I half assumed that reactive_ble would've stripped the leading checks and only supplied the the necessary portions of the data object that's relevant to interpret, however, this does not seem to be the case.

My first feel was to just convert this UInt8List to String `utf8.decode(device.manufacturerData)`, however, this returns either a 1x spaced string or nothing at all.

I've tried using ByteData with a start of 3 and end of 4, and that's not very helpful either.

Is there something I'm missing in it's interpretation? I've read the Bluetooth spec and as I don't come from a CompSci background, is rather foreign to me, so would appreciate a layman response.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first 16 bits (little endian) in manufacturer data contain the manufacturer id (Bluetooth SIG's web site has a list). The layout of the rest of the bytes are totally up to the manufacturer. If you can't guess what they mean, you'll have to ask the manufacturer.

Comment: that's correct. I couldn't figure out what the rest of the information pertains to, however, I found a Reddit post where something similar was discussed, and I could deduce the rest. Thanks.